# What does "pairwise" distribuion in the R gbm package mean?

Tags: r, boosting

In the R [gbm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gbm/versions/2.1.5/topics/gbm) function (within the gbm R package), the **distribution** argument can get the value "pairwise". The help document states:

[image]

I would like your help in understanding what is that "pairwise" regression exactly? 
Moreover, what is the cut-off which the **max.rank** parameter is used for?

Comment: I am also trying to understand this feature. I wrote a note to Brandon Greenwell (who is listed in the documentation as the maintainer), and I opened an issue in github. In both places I pointed to your question. I let you know what I find. If you find something about "pairwise," consider answering your question to share the findings.